# How can I discharge static electricity from my body?

Tags: esd, motherboard, pc, static-electricity

I am planning to install a PCI Express Wifi-adapter in my PC. In order to do this, I would need to open my PC. I'm worried that if there is static electricity in my hands it could fry the motherboard.

I don't have an anti-static wristband, nor do I have an ESD mat. Is there a still a safe way for me to install the PCI Express Wifi-adapter without frying the motherboard?

Comment: Safe way: use a USB adaptor.

Comment: @Andyaka I already have the PCI Express Wifi-adapter at home.

Comment: Touch a screw on a light switch or outlet

Comment: @DKNguyen do you mean this screw on the outlet: https://i.imgur.com/pUrmApO.png or do you mean that I would need to open the outlet?

Comment: Normally the screws holding electrical stuff to the wall is grounded. No need to open.

Comment: @DKNguyen would the screw I put an arrow at also be grounded since that's the only screw I see.

Comment: Yes. Your outlet is a bit more unsettling because it is so recessed.

Comment: Before you open your PC, touch an uninsulated part of its metal case. Repeat periodically during the process. Better still, tether yourself to the PC case with a wire in series with a 1 Mohm resistor (resistor is for your safety against shock, not any part of making the grounding work).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions :)

Comment: @DKNguyen this particular outlet has earth ground on those easily accessible top and bottom contacts

Comment: Rub you feet on a carpet and then touch your best friend. Static removed.

Comment: @DKNguyen That only works in certain countries. Nor all have exposed screws grounded.

Answer (score 2):

You worry too much. Go to an area with least possible sources of static electricity, e.g. no carpet. The adapter most likely comes in a ESD bag. Open the PC and touch the PC metal parts while holding the adapter bag, take out the adapter, hold the metal bracket, touch the PC metal case again, and there should now be no potential difference between the adapter, you and the PC. Mount it in the slot and close the PC. Done.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bare copper wire that you wrap around your arm/leg and connect to something which is connected to ground like your radiator.

Comment: Works great until you touch a live part and can not let go of that wrap around. Should be a painful death. There is a 1 megaohm resistor in series with comercial hand straps for this very reason.